# Vapor trail disappears then reappears

Tags: commercial-aviation, jet-engine, weather, jet

I was watching a commercial jet and the vapor trail was moving and disappearing very quickly. I should note that it is currently 61 F on the ground, but the morning has been cool. (Min 34 F) I don't know what vapor trails do under certain conditions, but I would assume that in warmer weather the vapor trail would completely disappear more quickly, but that doesn't seem to be the case in the summer. Anyway, the weird part was when the vapor trail completely disappeared or cut off. The plane stopped producing a trail for about 15 seconds and the plane was hard to see during this period. After that the trail reappeared and resumed as normal. I also noticed that the trail hung around much longer and dispersed more than all the other trails from planes that recently flew by. Perhaps the plane entered an area of air that was different in temperature than the air around it. Has anyone seen or heard of this and have any idea why this would happen?
Thanks

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to the site.  [It just passed through a mass of air not moist enough for condensation to form](http://contrailscience.com/broken-contrails/). As to why it hung around for longer, the wind at it's altitude was weaker than at other levels.  I don't know why you were downvoted, no valid reason I can see, so I've reversed it and then some with a +1.

Comment: Simon is right its just not moist enough. Like somedays it rains and somedays doesn't just depends on the moisture in the air.